# Как правитльно получить данные из XML по шаблону c помащю XSL

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt

Добрый день!

Пытаюсь по этому XML получить все записи по шаблону "с" и одна цифра.

```
<XML>
    <Row>
        <cell>
            c1
        </cell>
        <cell>
            c2
        </cell>
        <cell>
            a1
        </cell>
    </Row>
</XML>
```

Вот XSL стили:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="/Row">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains(/Cell/text(),'c')">

            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

> Результат: c1 c2 a1
>
> Что мне нужно: с1 с2

В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение:

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">    
    <xsl:variable name="vDigits" select = "'0123456789'"/>

    <xsl:template match="cell">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test= "(starts-with(.,'c') = 'true')
                                    and 
                             (translate(substring-after(.,'c'),$vDigits,'') = '')">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/> 
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                nope
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```